# Can't Create Azure File Share: The remote name could not be resolved: 'calcpaebooks.file.core.windows.net'

Tags: azure

I can't create a Azure File Share.  Followed instructions in

http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/09/23/step-by-step-create-a-file-share-in-azure.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx#faq7

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/06/06/new-azurestorageshare-the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved-fileservices-file-core-windows-net.aspx

I went in Azure Preview Portal and signed up for the File Share.  I got an email form Microsoft saying: "Your subscription to the Microsoft Azure Files preview has been activated"

But, I get an error message in Azure Power Shell that "The remote name could not be resolved: 'calcpaebooks.file.core.windows.net' "

What an I doing wrong?

Comment: We have the same problem, Azure Files was enabled in our account, but we cannot create a share

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create File Share through GUI in Azure Preview Portal.

Select a storage account, it will load the detail page of the storage account. In this page, click Files (Services tab), it will load the list of your file shares (if any). In the next page, click File shares (you should click the header of the File shares container, not the list area). There is a File Share button in the next page. Just clicking it to create new File Share.

Hope this helps.
BBN.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping `calcpaebooks.blob.core.windows.net` but not `calcpaebooks.file.core.windows.net`?

If so Azure Files is probably not enabled or not authorized. We had the same problem. You need Azure Files to be enabled **and** authorized. Get in contact with the subscriptions team to get it authorized.

See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2014/06/06/new-azurestorageshare-the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved-fileservices-file-core-windows-net-i-created-a-new-storage-account-but-dont-see-the-file-service-on-the-portal/) msdn blog post for more information.